# Acer Aspire One AOA110 randomly hard blocks WLAN0 - How to stop it

Tags: acer, aspire-one, ath5k

My Aspire One netbook is now a *not*book.

It's an AOA-110 that has worked fine forever and a day (currently with Maverick UNR, fully updated).  Last night, I was ereading and went to go online to look something up.  I notice that not only am I not connected, but my AP is not even visible.

Okay.  Research time.

I find out about RFKILL.  It is showing a hard block on the ATH5K device.  The switch is NOT flipped.

Among other things, I have tried remapping the switch and the steps listed in #49 [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/478036).

Unfortunately, between this, the current [UDEV worker error](https://bugs.launchpad.net/udev/+bug/647404), the [fullscreen Flash video error](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/660127), and apparently narrowly avoiding the [devkit SSD issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/fedora/+source/devicekit-disks/+bug/445852), and the perennial lack of progress on Launchpad (as well as two weird errors on two Wubi installs done to make converts), I am losing all faith in Ubuntu.

In addition, even when a hard block seems to be missing, neither Network Manager nor Wicd seem to see the AP I know is there and in range.  iwlist scan shows no results, and iwconfig shows the WLAN0 interface.

Enough discussing, on to questioning.

How can I fix this?  Secondly, any ideas on why this is happening?

I am desperately fighting a complete reinstall.  Any help out there?

Comment: it appears to me that most of the "problems" you are referencing come back to buggy firmware on newer netbooks.  mine is older, but continues to work just fine.

Comment: I doubt you might consider a two year old netbook newer, but okay...

Comment: The OP [says this is working now and wants this closed](http://askubuntu.com/a/14616/22949). As far as I can tell, no answer that is known to work was posted. So we should consider closing this as *too localized*.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, ensure you're using the most current bios.  Secondly, I'm presuming you've set rfkill to soft-unblock the device.  Thirdly, I'm presuming you've purged hal from your system (which would be the default state if you did a fresh install of Lucid or Maverick).  Fourthly, [have you filed a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) against the linux source package with `ubuntu-bug linux` ?

Comment: Weird.  Let the battery full drain, charged it back up, and no problems.  I try to do that every so often to keep the battery life high.

Comment: I haven't had this problem in a LONG time.  of course I have disabled sleep/hibernate completely as this was a bone of contention for a long time and disabling was acceptable for me.  in my opinion, for me it wasn't random.  it was a resume from suspend/hibernate/low power problem.  i accept a certain level of buggy in exchange for free and open.

Comment: @Samizdata Actually, this trick with battery drain does not work and can sometimes even make things worse.

Answer (score 0):

It still seems to be working, so I will close this and let people get on with the more urgent questions.